# Sections and complements commute.

Tags: measure-theory, elementary-set-theory

In Measure theory (Cohn) page 155 he defines the $\textit{sections}$
$$E_x = \{y\in Y :(x,y) \in E\}$$
where $E\ \subset X\times Y$
Then later in the proof of Lemma 5.1.1 he states 
$(E^c)_x = (E_x)^c$. What have I missed?

Wouldnt a simple counter example be:
$X \times Y = \{(1,1); (1,2); (2,1); (2,2)\}$
and $E = \{(2,2)\}$
then $(E_x)^c = \{2\}^c = {1}$ but $(E^c)_x = (\{(1,1); (1,2); (2,1)\})_x=  \{1,2\}$

What am I missing?
Can someone point me to my error and help me with a proof?

Comment: Implicit in your counterexample is that $x=2$, in which case you've calculated $(E^c)_x$ wrong.

Comment: I see so in the definiton there should be $\forall x$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$(E^c)_x = \{y\in Y : (x,y) \in E^c\} = \{y\in Y: (x,y) \notin E\} = \{y\in Y : (x,y)\in E\}^c = (E_x)^c$$